# How to check if new day has started in other timezone in php

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, timezone

I have this code and I want to check if a new day has started in other timezone, let's say in "America/New_York".

```
$productMarketTime = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$productMarketTime = $productMarketTime->format('h:i a');
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i a', '12:05 am');
$end = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i a', '06:30 am');
dd([
   'now' => $productMarketTime,
   'start' => $start,
   'end' => $end,
   'condition' => $productMarketTime > $start && $productMarketTime < $end
]);
```

but it is not working correctly, I want this condition to be true when the time is between `12:05 am` and `06:30 am`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your second line turns `$productMarketTime` into a string, but `$start` and `$end` aren't strings, so you seem to be trying to compare a string directly with a `DateTime` object, which isn't going to work.

Comment: so should I try it with ```Carbon::parse($productMarketTime)``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the date objects in the comparison... Not the strings returned by `.format()`. Also, make sure to use the same timezone on every dates to compare.

```
<?php
$newyork_tz = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
$now_newyork = new DateTime('now', $newyork_tz);
$start = new DateTime('12:05 am', $newyork_tz);
$end = new DateTime('06:30 am', $newyork_tz);

$condition = $now_newyork > $start && $now_newyork < $end; // true/false
?>
```

[Demo on paiza.io](https://paiza.io/projects/sXcrmteBx6db98Gb41x0YA)